# MongoDB on Archlinux without compiling from source

Tags: mongodb

I can't seem to find a precompiled package that works for Arch. I believe I've tried all the debian-style packages, to no avail. There is no longer an actively-managed mongodb package. And compiling from source apparently requires like a couple hundred gigs of space. Is there a way to get an binary on Arch for MongoDB without compiling from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully install and run mongodb 6 from this [binary build](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:justkidding:arch/mongodb) in an arch vm, and it is actually compiled against a recent version of openssl 3.0 unlike what is in AUR. Download the zst, run `pacman -U` against it, and `sudo systemctl start mongodb.service` after editing `/etc/mongodb.conf` to your liking.

(PS "justkidding" is the name of the repo owner on the buildserver, this is not a joke link).